# Adding the last n element of a sorted set to another

Tags: java, mergesort, treeset

I have two TreeSets `A` and `B`. I want to merge the last n element of `B` into `A` in an efficient way, ie. using merging of sorted sets.

Is there an efficient way to do this implemented in Java.

The only way I see is to find `n`-th smallest element of `B`: `b_n`, get the view of the tailSet, then call `A.addAll(B.tailSet(b_n))`, but this is not good enough for us, as this would require additional `n` iterations in `B` and calling `tailSet()` is also not free.

The optimal scenario would be something like `A.addFromTail(B, n)` using the same merging technique as `addAll` but stopping after adding `n` element.

Comment: Would it be fine to use streams to do the work?

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSet` has an `descendingIterator` which allow you to do something like

```java
Iterator<String> iterator = b.descendingIterator();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a.add(iterator.next());
}
```

Another way would be using Stream API (since Java 8) with

```
Iterator<String> iterator = b.descendingIterator();
a.addAll(Stream.generate(iterator::next).limit(Math.min(n, b.size())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

`TreeSet.size()` has a complexity of O(1) so this could be lightweight and you only go through the last N elements of B.

Comment: Computing the size will be lightweigth, but you'll have some overhead for the `.stream().skip(all but the last Ns)`. The Stream will need to emit all items that will be discarded

Comment: I wonder if `skip(k)`  is O(1) or O(k). But also when we are collecting the trimmed set it must be O(k), so we are not really faster then finding the k-th element then using `tailSet`.

Comment: You're right. I looked to implement the stream from the ```descendingIterator```  to use the ```limit(n)``` instead, but it's kind of tricky with the standard Stream API.
The first solution is probably better

Comment: It just feels a bit disappointing in general that finding the n-th element in a TreeSet is O(n) and not O(log n).

Comment: The data structure of the TreeSet imposes that you can't get indexed values. But depending of your context, maybe you can use another data structure ?

Comment: There is actually a method within TreeSet called `buildFromSorted(int size, Iterator<?> it,
java.io.ObjectInputStream str, V defaultVal)` (the last two args are not important and also optional). which is exactly what I would want by setting size to my limit, but as fate would have it this method is private...

Comment: There's another way of doing this with Stream, using the descendingIterator

```Iterator<String> iterator = b.descendingIterator();
a.addAll(Stream.generate(iterator::next).limit(Math.min(n, b.size())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
``` I edit my answer to share this approach as it's better than the original Stream version.

Comment: My problem with this is when collecting to a list we lose the nature of having a sorted set. And `TreeSet.addAll ` optimizes the bulk-insertion if the given argument is a SortedSet. That is why I wrote `A.addAll(B.tailSet(b_n))` in my description.